# error 1191 in database when doing a search

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have been trying to resolve this issue for a while but I'm stuck.

I have a error keep throwing up every time I do a search on my website for "eastlincs" but I'm not sure how to fix the issue.

I have googled the error and there is not much about it and have read a couple of threads on here about the problem but I'm unable to fix the issue. I know its something to do with my database and adding the FULLTEXT to categories in my database.

The error being displayed:

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1191
>   Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

This is the actual query:

```
SELECT 
    c.id, c.type_id, 
    MATCH(c.name) AGAINST('>eastlincs eastlincs*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS categories_name_score, 
    MATCH(c.meta_title) AGAINST('>eastlincs eastlincs*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS categories_meta_title_score, 
    MATCH(c.meta_description) AGAINST('>eastlincs eastlincs*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS categories_meta_description_score 
FROM (categories AS c) 
WHERE MATCH(c.name, c.meta_title, c.meta_description) AGAINST('>eastlincs eastlincs*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY (categories_name_score*1.25+categories_meta_title_score+categories_meta_description_score*1.20) DESC
```

**UPDATE:** table definition:

```
categories
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `type_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `parent_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `tree_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `order_num` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `seo_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `selected_icons_serialized` text NOT NULL,
 `meta_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `meta_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `en_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'untranslated',
 `en_meta_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'untranslated',
 `en_meta_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'untranslated',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `parent_category_id` (`parent_category_id`),
 KEY `tree_path` (`tree_path`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`,`meta_title`,`meta_description`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `meta_title` (`meta_title`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `en_name` (`en_name`,`en_meta_title`,`en_meta_description`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `en_meta_title` (`en_meta_title`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `meta_description` (`meta_description`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=79 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PACK_KEYS=0
```

Comment: let's try making `meta_description` to be a separate FULLTEXT key: ALTER TABLE categories ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `meta_description` (`meta_description`); Run it and see if meta_description is shown with `FULLTEXT KEY`  when you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE categories` again.

Comment: How would you suggest to do that?

Comment: delete the old one?

Comment: updated the update of database table

Comment: do you still get the original error after you run your query again? We can discuss further in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136490/discussion-between-andrews-and-richard-epton

Comment: I've updated the answer, see below. You may need to add the additional `FULLTEXT` key for single name column.

Comment: @andrews very sorry, i lost internet for the last few hours but i have just tried your last update and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is quite self descriptive:

> Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

You are trying to use FULLTEXT search query against columns which may have not been added to the FULLTEXT index. Maybe your full text index doesn't exist at all.

So check the existence of your FULLTEXT index and if it exists, check the actual list of columns included in the index.

You can check the indexes defined for your table like this:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM categories;
```

More specifically check the list of columns in the FULLTEXT index if it exists:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE (table_schema, table_name) = ('mydatabase', 'categories')
  AND index_type = 'FULLTEXT'
ORDER BY seq_in_index;
```

(replace mydatabase with your actual db name)

and see if `name`, `meta_title` and `meta_description` are listed. If not, you need to add the missing columns to your index.

**UPDATE:** 
You do FULLTEXT query against `name`, `meta_title` and `meta_description` separately from each other and then against 3 columns at once: `MATCH(c.name, c.meta_title, c.meta_description)`.

So I think you're missing separate `FULLTEXT` keys for `name` and `meta_description`:

```
ALTER TABLE categories ADD FULLTEXT INDEX meta_description (meta_description); 
ALTER TABLE categories ADD FULLTEXT INDEX name1 (name);
```

HTH

Comment: its been puzzling me for ages but i just cant figure it out

Comment: column_name
meta_title
en_meta_title
name
en_name
meta_title
en_meta_title
meta_description
en_meta_description

Comment: @RichardEpton could you add the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your `categories` table to your question?

Comment: thats the results from your last message

Comment: i dont have the create table any more, the website use to work ok but i left it for a while as i work in progress but now dosent work

Comment: just run `SHOW CREATE TABLE categories`

Comment: dint know that one, sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136490/discussion-between-andrews-and-richard-epton).

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, then came here.

I did a change of language, which caused the issue.
dropping index, and adding again did not solve it.

but dropping, and adding with different name for the index solved it.